# how can I get the vnet id into a variable using Azure CLI

Tags: azure

I want to get the vnet id of an azure vnet into a variable using azure cli.

i then want to use this variable in the azure devops pipeline and populate a variable there?

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) making use of the [az network vnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet?view=azure-cli-latest) commands, e.g.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource Manager service connection>
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az network vnet show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVNet
```

In the same task's inline script you're free to use any powershell, so could also [set variables in that script](http://az%20network%20vnet%20show%20-g%20MyResourceGroup%20-n%20MyVNet) for use in subsequent steps.  Hope this helps!

Comment: How is that getting a vnet id? the command is incomplete.
you should use `az network vnet -n vnetName -g vnetRgName --query name  -o tsv`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
getNetID=$(az network vnet list --query "[?name=='myVNET'].id" -o tsv)
```

Then I reuse the bash variable later in my pipeline task:

```
--remote-vnet "$getNetID"
```